# Iterm2 Customized Key Mapping does not work as Vscode Shell

Tags: visual-studio-code, iterm2

I have configured my Vscode to use ITerm2 as the built-in shell.
However, my customized key mapping does not work inside the Vscode. But it does work in external standalone ITerm2.

For example, in VScode ITerm2, Option + H combination displays the escape character, as shown.
[image]

But in external ITerm, it moves the cursor left, as expected due to my key mapping configuration, as below.
[image]